# How do I turn my class into a library I can import? (Java)

Tags: java, class, import

Okay, so I have this class, it has many, *MANY* functions, and I intend to add more. You know when you import stuff like java.util.*;? How do I turn this class into that? I intend to use this class for many future projects.

I wish to turn this class into a library that I can import, so that I can call functions from it without first instantiating it.

Comment: `...  so that I can call functions from it without first instantiating it.` - that has nothing to do with a "library". You import *packages*, so that you can use types (classes, enums, interfaces) from it without using their fully qualified name. You might want to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: library in java is nothing but `jar`, so create a jar, and use it anywhere.

Comment: As long as it's a simple class and you don't use a build tool, all I'd do would be to copy the .java file into every project that you want it in. And to not have tho instantiate it: make the methods `static`, that's all that is needed.

Answer (score -1):

enter the folder your .class  files exist.then run DOS jar cvf jar_name.jar root_folder/*
jar_name is the jar you want name,root_folder is root folder of your .class file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGnq7.png)